# Display preconditions in a tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, tooltip, preconditions

I have some conditions to make true some variables. For example a button make boolean2 true. But if you want to make boolean2 true, you must make boolean1 true before then boolean2. So it's a precondition. Preconditions can be exist  more than one. If preconditions are not okay, I want to warn my users with a tooltip or popup when they press (mousedown) the button. In this tooltip or popup, I will show my users all preconditions and change colors whichs are not okay. When the user mouse up the button, tooltip or popup will be disappear.

What is the best way of it?

Comment: Don't. Instead use a tooltip the way it's meant to be used, on hover, and disable the button until all preconditions are met. If you show a tooltip on click and remove it on release, it will not be a good user experience.

Comment: Do you mean *validation*? [Random link](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) (see "Data validation" chapter).

Comment: @DrewJordan If All conditions are ok I will display an OK picturebox near the button. But if even one condition is not ok I will display NotOK picturebox. And When user want to see which condition is not ok, he will click the picture box and will see NotOK condition or all conditions where NotOK conditions are red color.

Comment: @Sinatr I will look data validation